# .htaccess php get error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to the .htaccess thing and did a couple of routing which worked fine but i just realised that my $_GET[] is being discarded. please how do i fix this.

Below is my PHP code:

```
<?php echo $_GET['er']?>
```

and my .htaccess code:

```
#turn rewrite engine on
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^signup/([0-9]+)$ -/register.php?er=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont think the slash before the $1 should be there

Comment: please give an example of a full signup URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^signup/([0-9]+)$ -/register.php [QSA,L]
```

so when the request

```
http:.../register.php?er=test;
```

You can now $_GET["er"] from within your php file.

an example that worked for me

`RewriteEngine on
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP is trying to achieve. In the code provided, what's after `/signup/` is passed to the `er` get parameter. The signup URL doesn't necessarily contains an `er` parameter.